# Menubar closed with last window - Xojo

Tags: menubar, xojo

I am working on a desktop application in Xojo (Realbasic) that I want to use with both Mac and Windows - so I associated the menubar with each window (so it will work on Windows).

I was working with the application when I happened to close the last window and then the entire menubar disappeared. Not sure why or where to look to fix this.

Comment: Can you add the code associated with this problem to your question?

Comment: In Xojo, you just associate the menubar with the window. In this case, I associated the main menubar with the window - because in Windows, menubars are related to the window and not the application.

Comment: On a Mac, it is an application menubar instead of a window menubar. Trouble is, that on Mac, when last window closed, the main menubar disappears and you have to quit and restart the application to get the menubar back.

Comment: Try assigning the menubar to the Application (App) object as well. That might help.

Comment: Did not even know that what an option. Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Let me add that as an answer then, so that you can give it a checkmark

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning the menubar to the Application (App) object as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your menubar might have disappeared if the application itself terminated, which Xojo can do for you automatically when the last window is closed.

Check the app.AutoQuit property. Normally you'll want that True on windows and False on Mac.